# Variational problem where the end point cannot be held constant

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I want to solve a variational problem for paths $y:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $F$ is a functional on the paths and additional parameter, and the end points are fixed, $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=b$. However, the problem is that the paths are functions of the parameter space $E$, and the functional $F$ depends on the parameter. The big problem is that it is extremely difficult to keep the end point $b$ fixed.

To be more precise we have a function $\mathrm{path}:[0,1]\times E\to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathrm{path}(0,e)=0$ but $\mathrm{path}(1,e)$ is not fixed. The functional is $\mathrm{Fun}:E\to [0,\infty)$ (which requires a calculation of the path). The variational problem to solve is to minimise $\mathrm{Fun}:E_b\to [0,\infty)$, where
$$
E_b=\big\{  e\in E :  \mathrm{path}(1,e)=b    \big\}\ .
$$
The problem is because $\mathrm{path}$ is only specified as a solution to differential equations with parameters that it is difficult to describe $E_b$.

The original problem is a length minimisation in noncommutative geometry, where the parameter space is the noncommutative vector fields, and the paths are given by solving a differential equation given the vector fields (this the problem in keeping the end point fixed). The functional depends on both path and the vector field.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received. I would be happy to supply more details if required.

Comment: Only a comment, but have you thought about trying to adapt the tools of variational inequalities to your problem? These problems involve boundary conditions that are a priori not known, and thus, at least from a conceptual point of view, similar to the one you are dealing with.